# Add an column and populate it with values that match another column in the table (kind of like vlookup)

Tags: sql-server

I wrote the query below. I want to add a new column to that called "Visited Site". In this column I want to have a "Y" for the sites that have been visited and "N" for the ones that haven't. I want this to match the site# column that is already there. I have a list of sites already that I want to use but it is in Excel. This would be the ideal case.

If not this then having that separate column called "visited site" which I can populate with the sites that have been visited and they match the site# column so when I export to excel i can filter on the blanks to know which ones are missing.

I'm not sure what to use. Inset function? I have the list of sites that are visited.

```
SELECT a.[Week End Date]
      ,a.[Cal Year #]
      ,a.[Week #]
      ,b.Category
      ,b.Department
      ,a.[Site #]
      ,SUM(a.[$ Sales])
      ,SUM(a.[Qty Sales])
  FROM databases.cbg.tableA a
  join databases.cbg.tableb as b on a.[UPC Code]=b.[UPC Code] and a.[Week End Date] = b.[Week End Date]
  where a.[Cal Year #] >= '2018'
  group by 
  a.[Week End Date]
      ,a.[Cal Year #]
      ,a.[Week #]
      ,b.Category
      ,b.Department
      ,a.[Site #]
     -- ,a.[$ Sales]
     -- ,a.[Qty Sales]
  order by a.[Week End Date] asc
```

Sample:

```
Week_end_date| Category| Site#| $_sales| Qty_Sales| Visited Site|
2019-01-01     Hardware  1000   7.99      1          1000
2019-01-01     Hardware  1010   8.99      1
```

I have a list of sites that my reps are suppose to visit, if they have visited it will be Y or else N and I have a list of sites they have visited and I wanted to input those into the visited site or just have a "Y" or "N" in there instead, either or works for me.

Comment: Sample data and expected results will really help us. It seems like you're describing a `JOIN`.

Comment: Sorry for making a duplicate I couldn't see any replies on here till I actually opened this question so I was confused if anyone even saw it.